# can i create a database without mysql on raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, database, apache2, raspberry-pi

I've got a raspberry pi with raspbian and all I've done is installed apache2 and created a small web site i want to create a database.
is this possible without using mysql or other database software. i want to use  .JS or a text based database
I want to be able to save the contact details in a text format.
can someone point me in the right direction a simple example would be appreciated all online research wants mysql etc 
all i want is a simple example as in enter name and submit i want that name to be logged so if name entered again it will say welcome back once i know this mechanism i can add all the other fields. The reason i want this format is so i can see the list that I'm creating.
i just can't get to grips with mysql I've spent months trying to understand mysql but its just not going in so want to simplify the database to minimal workings so i can complete my site. I know .Js isn't so secure but its a demo so security not important at this point any help appreciated

Comment: Do you consider other databases?

Comment: i looked into databases to install own cloud and kid safe but i just don't get them i know .js and txt databases are possible with security risks which don't bother me at this point. i can create login page no prob but i have to manually edit users into the code on the html page. I want to understand databases but i just don't and its holding me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible to use JSON for your data storage. It will be a key-value storage. On each page view you will have to load the entire file into memory and parse it. From then on it is possible to loop it to search data or get data from a key. This requires no extra software just PHP with Apache.

How to:
Build an array, use json_encode to create the JSON and save it using file_put_contents(). Remebmer to save the whole array and not just the newly added element.

This is not a relative database but might do the trick if you build an intelligent system with cookie's to store an ID that is associated with a user.

Alternative you could use serialize() instead of json;

Comment: ill be honest don't understand a word of that please don't think I'm stupid but its beyond my understanding at this point i just want a html page and a file to store the names as submitted

Comment: `//saving
$name = $_POST['name'];
$id = sha1(microtime());
$database = json_decode(file_get_contents("dataset.json"), true);
$database[$id] = $name;
file_put_contents("dataset.json", json_encode($database));
setcookie("dataid",$id,time()+3600,"/");
//retrieve
$database = json_decode(file_get_contents("dataset.json"), true);
echo $database[$_COOKIE["dataid"]];`

Something like this, needs debugging since I just wrote it down in here. Also add some security and data integrity checks!

Comment: ok so this is using java quick browse and no mention of mysql or other DBs good sign. ill research this method more a simple example would be great though, I break examples down easily and work out what line does what

Comment: The code provided is a little example. Break it down by reading what the functions do on php.net. Also read some more about cookie's. I've used them the keep track of the current active user and retrieve the info of that user.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use different way of storing data you can use either Google App Engine or [mongolab](https://mongolab.com) or other cloud based databases

Comment: I'm sure your correct but its beyond my understanding i want it all on the raspberry pi i know it can be done just need simple example

Comment: For example, if you use Google App Engine all your data will be stored on your local computer. But if you have a little experience the idea to store date in json files locally is good.

Comment: yes exploring JSON found simple sqlite demo as well. http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/11/getting-started-with-databases-on-pi.html done this ok still don't understand how to add users on own cloud etc but its a start the JSON is more what i want though cheers for the help